# Multiple conditions in custom format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, cell-format

I would like to have multiple formatting conditions eg.

```
561 -> 561
1,100 -> 1.10K
2,220,000 -> 2.22M
45,200,000 -> 45.20B
```

I came up with following solution but it wont work:

```
[>=1000000000]#.00,,,"B";[>=1000000]#.00,,"M";[>=1000]#.00,"K";###
```

What can be done in this situation?

Comment: you can use conditional formatting and specify number format there.

Comment: @MátéJuhász thanks that helped me a lot. May I ask why I can't use it as presented above?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe you've tried to enter too many conditions.

Comment: Problem is max of two conditions in a number format I think (effectively you are re-using the negatives and zeroes with different boundaries). 
You will have to use conditional formats, but could use a combination eg conditional format for things >999999 then the first half of your custom format, then second condition for <1000000 and use the second half of your number format.

Comment: You've got four numeric formats and three conditions.  I think you can only have three numeric formats and two conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with conditional formatting rules instead of custom formatting. The difference is actually in the words themselves -> ***Conditional*** vs ***Custom***.

> *"Excel custom number formats have a specific structure. Each number
>   format can have up to four sections, separated with semi-colons as
>   follows:" [Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/custom-number-formats)*

[image]

- **1)** Positive values
- **2)** Negative values
- **3)** Zero values
- **4)** Text values

Since you have specified conditions for different types of positive values it won't fit in the custom format parameters! Go for conditional formatting instead, with three rules applied on e.g. column `A:A`:

- If value is greater or equal to `1000` then custom format: `#.00,"K"`
- If value is greater or equal to `1000000` then custom format: `#.00,,"M"`
- If value is greater or equal to `1000000000` then custom format: `#.00,,,"B"`

Put them in, in this order so on column A:A the order of the rules is reversed!

[image]

Mind you, in above example you'll notice my system uses a comma as seperator!